# Как работать с XML по принципу Ключ-значение?

Tags: java, android

Дело такое: мне нужно создать XML файл с ключом и значением без иерархии тегов. А из Java обращаться так: пишешь ключ — приходит значение. Рассмотрел `XmlPullParser`, но везде только описания типа: циклом перегнать все данные в список или в массив. А мне нужен метод, который будет получать строку (ключ) и возвращать строку (значение).

Comment: Если есть возможность отказаться от `xml` и посмотреть в сторону `json` - стоит это сделать (имхо). XML парсится в разы медленнее. Немного [статистики](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2016/04/19/mobile-performance-testing-json-vs-xml.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Есть 2 разновидности обработчиков ('parser`):

- DOM parser. Работающий по принципу построения объекта структуры файла. Одним из достоинств данного парсера является быстрая навигация по структуре.
- SAX parser. Работающий по принципу итератора, т.е. последовательного доступа (перебора) компонентов файла. Главным достоинством данного парсера является низкое потребление памяти и возможность обработки очень больших файлов.

Судя по задаче нужен именно SAX parser.

Примеров море по запросу SAXparser java. Например [вот](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)